# How do I use a socket to watch Twilio message queue?

Tags: node.js, sockets, twilio

I'm trying to get some information from the twilio queue. And in order to get that information i have to send requests every time i want to know whether or not the queue is full. Is there a way to kind of "watch" with the help of sockets to see if the queue is full or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post to derive the message queue based on message time stamps.

[How to Calculate Your Message Queue Length](https://www.twilio.com/blog/calculate-message-queue-length)